# Nexus `admin.password` file is missing in version 3.28.1

Tags: docker, nexus, nexus3

I've created a Nexus server using the official Docker image from Sonatype. My version is `3.28.1` and I can't find admin password or admin.password file in the usual place.

```
cat /opt/sonatype/sonatype-work/nexus3/admin.password
```

I've also tried default admin password `admin123` and it did not work?

I could not find any release notes about this change and I would like to know where to find the admin password.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any update? I have the same issue.

Comment: `docker exec -it nexus cat /nexus-data/admin.password`

Answer (score 5):

Make docker container using following command

```
$ docker volume create --name nexus-data
$ docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus -v nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3
```

Then you will find `admin.password` file in `/nexus-data` folder.
Run following command to see default password!

```
$ docker exec -it nexus /bin/bash
bash-4.4$ cat /nexus-data/admin.password
```

For more detailed comment, check following url

https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3/#user-content-persistent-data

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the [sonatype/nexus3](https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3) image? Then it should be in `/nexus-data`.

If it's not there, then the only solution I've found was to remove all the contents of the `/nexus-data` directory and restart the container. That should initialize a new config, including a new admin password, which should now be available at `/nexus-data/admin.password`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command to locate the file:

```
$ find / -name admin.password
```

it will show you the path.

Output in my setup:

```
/mnt/data/admin.password
```